# Linux Kernel hangs waiting for interrupt

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm64

I am bringing up linux kernel 5.5.0-rc1 on arm64 based embedded system.
The kernel initialization is done. but after that the kernel waits continuously for the interrupt.
below is the backtrace

```
(gdb) bt
#0  arch_local_irq_enable () at /home/sami/linux/arch/arm64/include/asm/irqflags.h:37
#1  arch_cpu_idle () at /home/sami/linux/arch/arm64/kernel/process.c:126
#2  0xffff8000106eb8d4 in default_idle_call () at /home/sami/linux/kernel/sched/idle.c:94
#3  0xffff8000100d9e3c in cpuidle_idle_call () at /home/sami/linux/kernel/sched/idle.c:154
#4  do_idle () at /home/sami/linux/kernel/sched/idle.c:269
#5  0xffff8000100da07c in cpu_startup_entry (state=CPUHP_ONLINE) at /home/sami/linux/kernel/sched/idle.c:361
#6  0xffff8000106e5888 in rest_init () at /home/sami/linux/init/main.c:451
#7  0xffff8000109b09e4 in arch_call_rest_init () at /home/sami/linux/init/main.c:572
#8  0xffff8000109b0e14 in start_kernel () at /home/sami/linux/init/main.c:784
#9  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Any ideas what could be the issue? why is the kernel not getting interrupt?

Comment: There's nothing to indicate it is "waiting for interrupt". I'd rather think, it has nothing else to do (you should check what's going on with root filesystem and init process).

Comment: in init/main.c , in start_kernel , at the end arch_call_rest_init is called. and it doesn't return. As it is blocked in arch_local_irq_enable() in arch/arm64/include/asm/irqflags.h, I thought it is waiting for the interrupt. What should happen after the arch_call_rest_init() call in start_kernel ?

Comment: Kernel is supposed to execute an user space `init` process, as I said. For some reason, it is unable to do so on your setup. `...irq_enable` has nothing to do with waiting, it merely allows the current CPU core to receive interrupts again (this is used to ensure non-preemption of kernel threads in critical places).

Comment: yes, before going to wait for interrupts, the kernel creates a thread kernel_init which was supposed to execute an user space init process.
But, this kernel_init thread calls schedule()..
init/main.c -> kernel_init -> kernel_init_freeable -> kernel/workqueue.c ->  workqueue_init -> init_rescuer -> kernel/kthread.c -> kthread_bind_mask -> wait_task_inactive->schedule()

Answer (score 0):

@Sami You got *past* the arch_local_irq_enable() call; gdb just still sees the pushed stack frame from the call.  I tend to agree with @oakad that your system simply has nothing to do, and to finish booting you should check:

1. Is time passing (i.e. are there timer ticks accumulating)?  This has bitten me before ... you don't readily get buffered console output without ticks.
2. You've gotten past initialising the console at this point.  Whether you prefer to step through via a JTAG debugger or do printk() calls to the console, you should be able to verify whether or not you are in the arch_cpu_idle() loop.
3. Can you verify that you have mounted a root filesystem?
4. If so, what happens when you specify init=/bin/bash on the kernel cmdline?  It ought to bring you into a simple shell, which is better than nothing.  You should also investigate using break={premount,mount,mountroot,modules,top,bottom,init} on the cmdline to see how far you are getting toward init.